# Flutter use future builder after tap search button instead of loading

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

**What I'm doing**
I'm making a search page, what I want to do is when I tap the search button, I call the request method to get the data, and when the data is ready, I render a new widget to the same page.

**What confuse me:**
I use Future Builder to achieve async loading . The example I got is loading data immediately when the screen is created, but my design is getting data after tap a button. I don't know how to do it.

**What I want to konw:**

1. How to use the FutureBuilder after taping a button (caused manually)?
2. What's the most elegant way to achieve my need?

**What I tried:**

after tapping a button, I Assign s Future builder to a *todoFuturebuilder*.

**Code**

Async function:

```
  Future<String> getSearchArtistResultList()async{ 
List<PopularArtistModel> result=await _searchArtistRequest.getSearchArtistResultList(widget.searchWords);
print(result);
if (result.length == 0) {
  return 'no_result';
}
setState(() {
  artistResultList.addAll(result);
});
return 'have_result';}
```

BuildMethod:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        getSearchBar(),
        Expanded(
            child: todoFutureBuilder
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Future Builder method(called when tapping a button):

```
 showSearchArtistResults() {
      todoFutureBuilder= new FutureBuilder(
        future: getSearchArtistResultList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == 'have_result') {
              return Expanded(child: buildArtistResultList());
            } else {
              return Text('No Result, Please Search Again');
            }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
      setState(() {
      });
  }
```

**Just in Case, the full code:**

```
class SearchArtistPage extends StatefulWidget{
  String searchWords='';

  SearchArtistPage({Key key,this.searchWords}):super(key:key);

  @override
  _SearchArtistPageState createState() => _SearchArtistPageState();
}

class _SearchArtistPageState extends State<SearchArtistPage>{
  String newSearchWords='';
  Future<String> futureArtistResultList;
  SearchArtistRequest _searchArtistRequest=SearchArtistRequest();
  List<PopularArtistModel> artistResultList=[];
  Widget todoFutureBuilder;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> getSearchArtistResultList()async{
    List<PopularArtistModel> result=await _searchArtistRequest.getSearchArtistResultList(widget.searchWords);
    print(result);
    if (result.length == 0) {
      return 'no_result';
    }
    setState(() {
      artistResultList.addAll(result);
    });
    return 'have_result';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        getSearchBar(),
        Expanded(
            child: todoFutureBuilder
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buildArtistResultList() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: artistResultList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,i)=>ArtistView(
            artistData:artistResultList[i]
        )
    );
  }


  Widget getSearchBar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(38.0),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                        blurRadius: 8.0),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 16, right: 16, top: 4, bottom: 4),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (String txt) {
                      newSearchWords = txt;
                    },
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Search by the artist name',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.pinkAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(38.0),
              ),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                    offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                    blurRadius: 8.0),
              ],
            ),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(32.0),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                  showSearchArtistResults();
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search,
                        size: 20,),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  showSearchArtistResults() {
      todoFutureBuilder= new FutureBuilder(
        future: getSearchArtistResultList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == 'have_result') {
              return Expanded(child: buildArtistResultList());
            } else {
              return Text('No Result, Please Search Again');
            }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
      setState(() {
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

1. Set a widget list, when click a button, add a new Future builder to it.
2. In future builder, the parameter future is the method runs when the future builder is created. So the rest of code is just like a normal future builder.